# FMX TEdit has bad behavior when keyboard is Microsoft Pinyin

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, ime

The expected behavior of an edit control is that the selected text is replaced by the new entered text.

However, this is not the case for a FMX.TEdit when the keyboard is Microsoft Pinyin (Chinese mode).

In that case, if (say) the text '12345' is selected, typing new text (say) '123', results is the edit showing (for example) '12312345'.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: The delphi version is 10.2.3

Comment: Suggest you try with Delphi 10.1 and see if the problem is there also. My hunch is that it was a bug introduced in 10.2.